# Set the language of a listings environment in pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, listings

I am struggling to convince pandoc to set the language for a listing automatically when converting from extended markdown (pandoc) to latex with the `--listings` argument. This is the file `foo.txt`:

```
A listing follows.

~~~{.prolog}
% fooing around
foo :-
    format("bar~n").
~~~~
```

When I use `pandoc -s foo.txt -o foo.html`, the code is highlighted.

When I use `pandoc -s foo.txt -o foo.latex`, the code is highlighted, using the custom commands inserted by pandoc in the LaTeX preamble.

When I use `pandoc -s foo.txt --listings foo.latex`, the code is not highlighted, as the `language` option to the listings environment is not set. I can work around this:

```
~~~{.prolog language=Prolog}
```

but this defeats the purpose. Am I missing something or is this functionality not supported? If it omitted on purpose, what is the reason?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, which version of pandoc are you using?http://hastebin.com/zaremokebo.tex

Comment: @MatthewPickering I was probably using an old version or a botched installation (I was on a customized Ubuntu 12.04 at work). Installing with cabal took forever but now the problem is gone.